# RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to best solution for this error of code and thanks

[image]

```
RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..12: 200
```

Comment: The solution would be to not pass in 200 as the `end` argument to `substring` on a string of length 12. You have to figure out why your code does that, which faulty assumptions it makes. In short: Your code has a bug, and you need to find and fix it. I can tell you that the call to `substring` is in `pages/home.dart` on line 100.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `substring` to limit the length of your String, use [`package:characters`](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) to convert the String in an Interable of characters and then take only the first X characters.

`take(n)` doesn't crash when the length is longer or shorter.

```dart
void main() {
  final longString = "This is a long String";
  final cropped = longString.characters.take(10).toString();
  print(cropped);
  // prints "This is a " 
}
```

Using `package:characters` is superior to substring because it also handles splitting of unicode characters correctly (such as emojis )

Answer (score 0):

This could also be caused by accessing you are accessing characters outside their available index. For example:

```
// This will result in month[0] to month[6] as accessible character.
const month = "January";
// Output: "J"
print(month[0]);
// RangeError similar to yours.
print(month[7]);
```

Pay attention to some lists in you code, you may found something from them.